# Ocultar ou exibir botão atraves de um ifelse com dados de um foreach

Tags: php

Galera tenho esse codigo, e o seguinte, preciso imprimir ou ocultar um botão de acordo com resultado do foreach, exemplo se estiver vazio quero que ele oculte o botão, se tiver algum item ele mostre o botão.

```
    <?php

    foreach( $types_list as $single_type ) {

        $yith_wapo_frontend->printSingleGroupType( $product , $single_type );

    }



    $product_id = yit_get_base_product_id( $product );

    $product_display_price = yit_get_display_price( $product );

    ?>
      </div>

        <button class="btn2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Concluído</button>

      </div>

    <?php
     $var = $product_id; 

    if( $var >= 1 ) {
    echo "<a href='#myModal' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Quero Personalizar</a>";    
    } else if ( $var = 0 ) {
    echo "<a hr

ef='#myModal' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal' style='display:none'>Quero Personalizar</a>";    
}


?>
```

Comment: O botão a esconder/mostrar é esse `<button class="btn2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Concluído</button>` ?

Comment: não, e o Quero Personalizar. Olha la o if else ali..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função `empty` de php para testar se o array tem algum elemento:

```
if( !empty($types_list) ) { //se não está vazio mostra
    echo "<a href='#myModal' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Quero Personalizar</a>";    
} else { //se está esconde
    echo "<a href='#myModal' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal' style='display:none'>Quero Personalizar</a>";    
}
```

Comment: Em partes o codigo tava certo, no caso no else if ali tive que tirar o If ...

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda Isac!

Comment: @BrunoRoberto sim, obrigado pela indicação que nem tinha reparado que tinha lá ficado